# Starting cmd.exe problem

Tags: c#, windows-7, cmd, autorun

In Windows, when a command prompt is opened (cmd.exe), the registry keys:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

are checked for a value called "AutoRun". If found, the batch file named in the value is executed, providing autoexec-like functionality. If both keys contain AutoRun values, both will be run. Awesome!

I'm using `Process.Start` to run cmd.exe and the AutoRun behavior is not occuring. My current code is:

```
private openShell( string folder )
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "COMSPEC" ) ?? "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/k cd \"" + folder + "\"",
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

    try
    {
        using ( var exeProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( startInfo ) )
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

I've also tried reducing it down to the simplest form:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "cmd.exe" );
```

Everything I try works perfectly (in that a command window is launched), but the AutoRun behavior never occurs.

Comment: Where's the code that checks the registry?

Comment: It's working, I didn't find any problem in the code

Comment: if you have put your "autorun" only in the HKLM key, your issue may be virtualization. Did you put something in the HKCU one and get nothing? Also, did you test this by hand-launching command prompts so you know the only issue is how your code launches them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. The problem was in how Windows stores (and retrieves) data from the registry in 64-bit versions of the operating system. My code was fine. The [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072%28VS.85%29.aspx) goes into some detail. From that article:

> On 64-bit Windows, portions of the
>   registry entries are stored separately
>   for 32-bit application and 64-bit
>   applications and mapped into separate
>   logical registry views using the
>   registry redirector and registry
>   reflection, because the 64-bit version
>   of an application may use different
>   registry keys and values than the
>   32-bit version. There are also shared
>   registry keys that are not redirected
>   or reflected.

The solution for me was to add my AutoRun key under:

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

What really gets my goat is that I've run into this before. I so rarely fool with the registry, I'd just completely forgotten about it.